# why so many jquery ajax files?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

```
            "~/Scripts/jquery-ui-{version}.js",
            "~/Scripts/jquery-ui.unobtrusive-{version}.js",
            "~/Scripts/jquery.validate-vsdoc.js",
            "~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js",
            "~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"
            "~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"
```

I am very confused about these files. I think not all of them are required when i want to turn a normal form into an ajax form. But am not sure which files to include.

**Can someone explain what is the role and use of each of these files ? and how are they related to Html.BeginForm or Ajax.BeginForm ?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I think not all of them are required when i want to turn a normal form
>   into an ajax form. But am not sure which files to include.

You only need `jquery` and `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax`. And the second is only needed if you are using the `Ajax.*` helpers. If you are manually AJAXifying your forms you don't need at all.

- `"~/Scripts/jquery-ui-{version}.js"` - The [jQuery UI plugin](http://jqueryui.com/)
- `"~/Scripts/jquery-ui.unobtrusive-{version}.js"` - I have strictly no idea, never used it
- `"~/Scripts/jquery.validate-vsdoc.js"` - documentation of the [jQuery.validate plugin](http://jqueryvalidation.org/)
- `"~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js"` - the [jQuery.validate plugin](http://jqueryvalidation.org/) itself
- `"~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"` - Microsoft's unobtrusive client side validation based on the jQuery.validate plugin. It allows you to have client side validation on top of the server side data annotations
- `"~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"` - makes the `Ajax.*` helpers actually work

Comment: if "~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js" is based on jQuery.validate plugin, do i need to reference "~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js" whenever referencing "~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js" ?

Comment: Yes, you need to. And you need to reference it **BEFORE** the `~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js` reference and **AFTER** the jquery reference (because this plugin is based on jQuery).

Comment: Thanks. I have a clear idea of all files now.